# Find mean for a given group by a given time period

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to take an average or mean of a given group per month.

```
    group    startdate      enddate     diff    percent

    A        04/01/2019     05/01/2019  160     11
    A        05/01/2019     06/01/2019  136     8
    B        06/01/2020     07/01/2020  202     5     
    B        07/01/2020     08/01/2020  283     7
```

For example:

I am wanting to take the mean per id per month. For group 'A',
for the month of April the **diff** is: 160 and for month of May, the diff is: 136.

The monthly **diff** mean for 'A' is 148
The monthly **percent** mean for 'A' would be: 9.5

Desired output

```
    group  diff_mean    percent_Mean

    A      148          9.5         
    B      242.5        6
```

This is what I am doing:

```
df.groupby['group'].mean()
```

I am not getting the correct output. I will keep researching. Any assistance is appreciated.

df.head()
[image]

Comment: Whats the problem with the output?

Comment: Simply do this: `df.groupby('group').mean()`. Your syntax is incorrect: `df.groupby['group'].mean()` Notice the difference between square brackets and parentheses.

Comment: Thank you David. This works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you just need a bracket around groupby-call; and also you cant average over the start/end-dates so ignore those from your dataframe:

```
df[['diff', 'percent', 'group']].groupby(['group']).mean()
```

Comment: Do I have to add df next to the groupby as well? It keeps saying key error 'group' (I am using the same sample dataset)

Comment: Whats the output of this cmd: `df.head()` ?

Comment: The name of your dataframe is `a`, not `df`? I hope you have replaced the name in the above cmd :)

Comment: I've just named it a , same data though. Yes

Comment: Whats the output of `df.columns` ?

Comment: @SerialLazer , you are not including `group` in your dataframe, so this will not work. IF you are trying to do it this way, then you would do: `df[['diff', 'percent', 'group']].groupby(['group']).mean()`. Please see my comment on the question as well, as you don't need to do this, at least in this sample dataset.

Comment: thanks @DavidErickson for pointing out, I have rectified it now.